# Symbol not found: _FSPathMakeRef

Tags: python, macos, pip, quartz

Can't import `Quartz` package.

I have installed it with this command `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`. Tried reinstalling python, also tried `python -m pip install ...`. With `python2` or `sudo python3`, everything works fine but `python3` is giving me this error message every time I try importing `Quartz`

Python version - 3.10.4

Mac version - Big Sur 11.6.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Quartz
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Quartz/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import AppKit
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/AppKit/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Foundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _objc
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _FSPathMakeRef
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
```

Comment: Can you uninstall and reinstall `pyobjc-framework-Quartz` ?

Comment: Tried, same error.

Comment: Try to compare `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc` and `/tmp/venv/lib/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc` to see what's different and why.

Comment: The only differences are in binary files.

Comment: Is `_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so`  the same in both directories ?

Comment: Yes, did `diff /tmp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so` and no output

Comment: The base python env where you want to install the package - how was this python setup? Using conda?

Comment: Also, please try `pip3 install pyobjc` and let us know the status - if it gets installed properly

Comment: Yes, everything is installed correctly. Error disappears if I execute it with the sudo.

Answer (score 1):

For investigation purposes, can you try :

```
cd /tmp
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
python your-script.py
```

Can you try this to see if it works :

```
env -i /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 my_script.py
```

You may have files only accessible by `root`, try to change ownership:

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10
```

and run `env -i ...` again.

If you run :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
```

Is there any difference between the two ?

Try following to see if it improves :

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

Try this to see if there is anything unusual :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -X importtest -v -c 'import Quartz'
```

Comment: Tried `env -i /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 my_script.py` same error as above. With `sudo env ...` works though.

Comment: Did `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10` and then `env -i ...` but the same error.

Comment: Both returned 

['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

Comment: `sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -m pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try:

```py
python3 -m pip install [...]
```

Hope this will hope.

Comment: I mentioned that I tried it, but it does not work

Comment: No, I mean there needs to be an extra 3. You used `python -m pip`, but mine is `python3 -m pip` notice that there is a `3`. perhaps this can solve your problem.

Comment: `python` is linked to the `python3` and they use the same alias, so it does not even matter I just put it there to avoid suggestions. But thanks for the try.