# Import error Symbol not found: _FSPathMakeRef

Tags: python, macos, python-import, importerror, sudo

Can't import `objc` package. Every time I try it throws an error and the weird thing is the error disappears if I execute the same thing with sudo privileges (`sudo python3 -c 'import objc'`). Tried reinstalling python also `find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages -user root -exec chown user {} \;` but didn't help.

Python version - 3.10.4

objc version - 8.5b1

Mac version - Big Sur 11.6.5

```
>which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
>sudo which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/unknown/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import objc
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _objc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _FSPathMakeRef
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
```

[Output](https://pastecode.io/s/gcur18tt) of `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages`

```
>find / -xdev -name libffi.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib
/System/Volumes/Data/opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib
/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib

>ls -lL "/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib" "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib" "/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib" "/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib" "/System/Volumes/Data/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib" "/System/Volumes/Data/opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib" "/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib" "/opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib"
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  139056 Dec  7  2020 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  139056 Dec  7  2020 /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/libffi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   71136 Oct 19  2021 /System/Volumes/Data/opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   32836 Aug 16  2021 /System/Volumes/Data/opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 user  admin   34516 Oct 25  2021 /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   71136 Oct 19  2021 /opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   32836 Aug 16  2021 /opt/metasploit-framework/embedded/lib/libffi.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 user  admin   34516 Oct 25  2021 /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib

>otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
    /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Tried with `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import objc'` but the same thing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/objc/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _objc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _FSPathMakeRef
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Comment: It probably accesses some administrator directory. If it works with sudo, use sudo

Comment: I have several python scripts which I use daily and entering sudo password is getting annoying.

Comment: True, let me look around and see what I can find.

Comment: Maybe try this : `pip install --user Quartz`

Comment: Tried, same error

Comment: Add `import CoreServices`, Carbon API is there now

Comment: `import CoreServices` throws the same error

Comment: If you can, try https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/uninstall-python-on-mac-os/ and reinstall from https://www.python.org/

Comment: I have done it already, but it does not fix the issue

Comment: Try `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz`

Comment: I don't think the `Quartz` package has something to do with it because I can't import `objc` so I will update the question. Btw I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have homebrew? Installing a fresh version of python using it may solve these permissions issues, as packages and such will be put elsewhere. `brew install python@3.10`

Comment: Tried with homebrew too. Same error.

Comment: sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyobjc
If it does not work try again without sudo

Comment: Looks like this particular function - FSPathMakeRef is deprecated in mac: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1565195-fspathmakeref. And this symbol might be associated with it:  _FSPathMakeRef. Can you check the version of objc and see if you can upgrade it to latest version. And try the script after upgrading objc to latest.

Comment: @ninjaconcombre I run `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyobjc` and had problems with permissions. Then I recursively changed the owner of every file to `user` it installed successfully but still had the same error.

Comment: @AnkitArora the version of `objc` I am using is `8.5b1`.

Comment: Run pip with sudo since beginning. if this work but you still have issues when having users permission pip remove pyobjc with user permission (to make sure user will use the previously system wide CLEAN installation and not his hacky one)

Comment: First I run with sudo I guess that's why on the second try it had issues with permissions but either way it didn't work.

Comment: Did you run through the steps here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672487/symbol-not-found-fspathmakeref

Comment: Yeah, but nothing helped so I started a new thread to be able to give bounty.

Comment: Can I ask why you forcefully deleted the `site-packages` folder?

Comment: Does that matter? :D

Comment: You have python `3.8` in `/Users/user/Library/Python/3.8`, not `3.10` reported previously.

Comment: I have them both. `3.10` is installed manually by me(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3) and `python3` is aliased to it. `3.8` (/usr/bin/python3) was there when I updated MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these comments in the form of an answer, for ease of formatting.

can you run in a Terminal :

```
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=1 DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/tmp/without-sudo.log python -c 'import objc'
```

in another Terminal, run `sudo zsh`, then run

```
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS=1 DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE=/tmp/with-sudo.log python -c 'import objc'
```

Now compare /tmp/without-sudo.log and /tmp/with-sudo.log to see if there are any differences.

On my BigSur, they are identical.

Update 1 :

At the end of your output, you have :

```
> dyld: loaded: <DE9AB8F9-5251-3940-8EE3-787EA6DF7531> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
> dyld: loaded: <D03C219A-1726-3769-A2CC-6A6441CBF457> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
> dyld: unloaded: <DE9AB8F9-5251-3940-8EE3-787EA6DF7531>
```

The problem might be due to libffi.dylib.

Can you run in your `sudo Terminal` ?

```
find / -xdev -name libffi.dylib
# my output
# /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
# /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libffi.dylib
# /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
```

then run :

```
ls -lL "/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libffi.dylib" "/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib"
# my output :
# -rwxr-xr-x  1 root        admin  175152 30 Nov  2020 /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.3.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libffi.dylib
# -rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff   71480 15 May 19:17 /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
# -rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff   71480 15 May 19:17 /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.4.2/lib/libffi.dylib
```

Update 2:

Can you run in both sudo and non-sudo Terminal ? and compare results

```
$ otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so
# my output :
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_objc.cpython-310-darwin.so:
# /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1858.112.0)
# /usr/lib/libffi.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
# /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
# /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Update 3:

I did following experiment on a test Big Sur:

```
1) sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
   # python -c "import objc" still working
2) Reboot MacOS
   python -c "import objc"
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objc'

3) sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
   Reinstall from www.python.org

4) python -c "import objc"
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'objc'

5) sudo python -V
   # Python 3.10.4, to make sure sudo is using the same python version

6) sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyobjc

7) python -c "import objc"
   # No output, meaning successful.
```

Comment: Yeah, they are different. The output of `diff /tmp/with-sudo.log /tmp/without-sudo.log` https://pastecode.io/s/920tsxvi

Comment: Added output in the question.

Comment: Updated again..

Comment: Thanks! I'm running out of ideas :-) Do you want to try other options ? like 1) Run sudo for your script. 2) set su-bit for python binary; or 3) Reinstall MacOS ?

Comment: I can add those scripts in the sudoers file and add NOPASSWD for them but also don't want to make the system vulnerable plus was hoping to find a better answer. I tried reinstalling MacOS too it didn't help)